# Illustrator Output color is different Saving file as Pdf

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When saving project in illustrator as pdf result colors are without original contrast.

Illustrator is showing me wrong colors or its saving wrong ones?

[image]

Comment: It looks like some RGB/CMYK confusion. The original looks like it's an RGB image and the pdf looks like it's been converted to some CMYK profile. Unfortunately your question lacks a lot of information so it's hard to tell exactly what is going on. Maybe you should start with reading up on RGB/CMYK. Lots of good questions on this site. And then we need to know: What is the color profile of the original image? What is the color mode of the Illustrator document? How do you save the pdf - do you convert to a CMYK profile? Which application do you view the pdf in?

Comment: Also it could be nice to know what the pdf should be used for. It's probably for print. Does the print house want you to use a certain CMYK profile or do you just want to make an RGB pdf? Be aware that the vibrant colors of the original might not be possible to print without some degradation.

Comment: You have provided **zero** information in order to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

All images are CMYK, and output is CMYK but there was color differences (in software and how it looks when saved as pdf).
Also appearance of black is fine.

**I found cause** - if you are using default pdf viewer and it opens file in **"EDGE"** colors are slightly different, but when you open it in any other browser like "Chrome", suddenly colors are similar.
Also same if you open it with Adobe Acrobat all colors are perfect.

Comment: Don't trust browsers (or Mac's Preview) to show correct colors of print pdfs. Only trust Adobe Acrobat.